# How to read from a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Solution, for at least a specific cell: GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;

I've build a simple CSV-Fileupload. After the user uploaded the file he should be able to evaluate the data. When the fileupload was successful the data gets loaded into the GridView1, with this code: (Problem below the code)

```
    string[] readCSV = File.ReadAllLines(lblFilePath.Text);  
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    bool bSplitMe = false;
    foreach (var rLine in readCSV)
    {           

        if (bSplitMe)
        {
            string[] aSplittedLine = rLine.Split(";".ToCharArray());
            try
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(aSplittedLine);
            }
            catch(System.Exception)
            {
                txtBoxFileOut.Text = rLine;
                break;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            if (rLine.ToLower().StartsWith("definedtestid;"))
            {
                bSplitMe = true;
                string[] aSplittedLine = rLine.Split(";".ToCharArray());

                foreach (var rCol in aSplittedLine)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(rCol);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                txtBoxFileOut.Text += rLine.ToString() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    dt.Columns.Remove("Column1");          

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)                      
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString())) 
            {
                dt.Rows[i][j] = "0";
            }
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;                                           
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

After this the user should be able to select a row and display the data from that row in a chart.
Problem: I'm not able to read data from the cells I want, or to read from a "hardcoded" cell.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

txtOutputfield.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a specific Cell this worked fine

```
txtOutputfield.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your cell index. Is it correct? For example: the third column will have index "2" not "3"

And, if you use a control to store the data, you need to find that control:

> txtOutputfield.Text  =
>   row.Cells[2].FindControl('placeyourcontrolnamehere').Text;

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, but i get this error: Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value', and it could no extension method 'Value' will be found that accepts a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' (missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: The cell index should be correct, the grid is 20*20. Sadly I'm not using a control to store the data.

Comment: have you try row.Cells["your_cell_name"].Text ?

Comment: Here i get the error: The best overload method has some invalid arguments.